# React-hook-form - enable/disable a button based on an input changes

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-hook-form, watch

Newbie-rookie-novice-junior front-end developer here. So sorry if this is obvious and I didn't see it...

So this is what I am trying to achieve:

I am using react-hook-form. Say I have a form with 4 fields. I add value for all of them, and when I click on "Save" button a new instance of those 4 fields appears. For every instance I have a "Modify" buton which calls a method that, of course, takes the index as a parameter. This is what the method looks like:

```
const handleModify = (index) => {

        const updatedBV = [...state.details.businessValues]; 
        const values = getValues();

        updatedBV[index] = values.details.businessValues[index];

        setState((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            details: {
                ...prevState.details,
                businessValues: updatedBV
            }
        }));
    }
```

And this is the button that triggers the function:

```
<Button type="button"
        otherClasses={"w-full disabled:opacity-25"}
        disabled={!savedStates[index] || (JSON.stringify(watch(`details.businessValues.${index}`)) === JSON.stringify(state.details?.businessValues[index]))}
        onClick={() => handleModify(index)}
    >
      Modify
</Button>
```

~ don't mind the "!savedStates[index]" ~

**So this works for the first modification**.
Example: I click the "Save" button -> "Modify" button is disabled.

I enter something in any of the fields -> "Modify" button is enabled.

I then press the "Modify" button -> again it is disabled.

**NOW**, when I again try to enter something in any of the fields, the button no longer gets enabled... So this is the problem that I am facing.

So I tried to see the difference between the watch(), getValues() and my form state so I added this:

`<h1>`**`watched fields`**`: {JSON.stringify(watch(details.businessValues.${index}))}</h1>`

`<h1>`**`getValues fields`**`: {JSON.stringify(val.details?.businessValues[index])}</h1>`
*(**val** here is a const equals to getValues())*

`<h1>`**`state fields`**`: {JSON.stringify(state.details?.businessValues[index])}</h1>`

The page reloads and the output is the same for all, empty values.

1. I fill all the fields and the values from watch() and getValues() changes but the values from state doesn't. Nothing WOW about that.
2. I save the form. Now, after save, the values from watch() (watched fields), getValues() (getValues fields) **and form state (state fields)** are the same. Modify button is disabled, of course, because of this line from the button that triggers the handleModify method:
   `` JSON.stringify(watch(`details.businessValues.${index}`)) === JSON.stringify(state.details?.businessValues[index]) ``
3. I type something in any of the field forms and "watched fields" and "getValues fields" are updated in real-time **but the form state ("state fields") are not**. This is great, now I can click the "Modify" button because this `` JSON.stringify(watch(`details.businessValues.${index}`)) === JSON.stringify(state.details?.businessValues[index]) ``  is no longer true and the button is no longer disabled. I click on it and the values of "state fields" are updated and the "Modify" button is again disabled.
4. Now comes the ugly part. When I try again to change an input of the form all 3 <h1>s are updated: watched fields, getValues fields **and state fields.** This is my problem, I don't want the state fields to be modified.

So my guess is that, by calling the handleModify method, I somehow change the form state behaviour by calling the getValues method on it.

I don't know what else I can try. Any other work-around on this? Or any other possible solutions for this? Maybe not the watch()/getValues() but something else?

Thanks for taking time to read this and sorry for making it so long. I didn't want to miss anything. However, if I did miss something or need more information, please let me know.